# Remove identical sequence of same numbers from data frame/vector

Tags: database, r

I have a dataset, which contains columns of "years", "code of the company" and "def - whether company defaulted". The problem I have is that the column of "def" contains a sequence of "1" for default. Those "1" is for all the years the company is in operation. So for instance the firm operates from 1990 and went out of business in the year 2000. The column contains 10 times "1" even though the company defaulted in the last year i.e. year 2000. So I should have instead column for this particular "company code" only "1" default entry for the year 2000 and not throughout the years 1990-2000. How can I remove the sequence of "1" from the column "def" (I have it now as data.frame) and just leave the last entry of "1" as actual default?

I have started by creating bins:

```
split(data.frame[dataFrame$def == 1, ], dataFrame[dataFrame$def == 1, 'coKey])
```

where the 'coKey' is the "company code".

I could not clean the data by leaving the last observation and neither was I successful in reversing the bins into the original data frame as the procedure to do so was too obsolete.

Thanks a lot for you help, much appreciated.

Here is sample data.

```
dataFrame <- structure(list(fyear = 1981:1986, 
   gvkey = c(1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L), 
   def = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L ), 
   .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), 
   .Names = c("fyear", "coKey", "def"), 
   row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you use `dput(dataFrame)` or a portion of it, `dput(head(dataFrame, 30))`?  That way we can see what you're working with exactly.

Comment: does your `def` column look like **`1111111`** (a single string) or like **`c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`** (a vector of 1's)

Comment: Thanks Justin: This is the output: > dput(head(dataMod))
structure(list(fyear = 1981:1986, gvkey = c(1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L), DEF = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("fyear", 
"gvkey", "DEF"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I'm sorry. The "gvkey" is the coKey=company code. The dataMod is the dataFrame. Column DEF is the "def" column of default (zero for no default and 1 for default). fyear, is the financial year of the company given the gvkey. My initial attempt was to place sample of the dataframe as a jpg file, but since its new account it would not allow.

Comment: Ricardo: is a vector of 1's, each corresponds to the same company (if defaulted) code (coKey=cvKey i.e. 1004) for number of years from starting company till the removal of the company = default.

Comment: Could be done with judicious use of `rle` to locate transitions from 1 to 0, but probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your comments I believe this is what you want, but I am not sure.

```
#Example data
df <- data.frame(fyear=rep(1981:1990,2),
                 gvkey=rep(c(1004,1005),each=10),
                 DEF=c(rep(0,2),rep(1,3),rep(0,5),rep(1,7),rep(0,3)))


library(plyr)

#function to apply by company
myfun <- function(x) {
  #check if last value is a 1
  if (last(x)==1) {
   res <- x*0
   res[length(res)] <- 1
  } else {
    #seach for difference between values == -1
    res <- as.numeric(c(diff(x),0)==-1)
  }
  res  
}

#split-apply-combine
ddply(df,~gvkey,transform,DEF2 = myfun(DEF))
```

Result:

```
  fyear gvkey DEF DEF2
1   1981  1004   0    0
2   1982  1004   0    0
3   1983  1004   1    0
4   1984  1004   1    0
5   1985  1004   1    1
6   1986  1004   0    0
7   1987  1004   0    0
8   1988  1004   0    0
9   1989  1004   0    0
10  1990  1004   0    0
11  1981  1005   1    0
12  1982  1005   1    0
13  1983  1005   1    0
14  1984  1005   1    0
15  1985  1005   1    0
16  1986  1005   1    0
17  1987  1005   1    1
18  1988  1005   0    0
19  1989  1005   0    0
20  1990  1005   0    0
```

Comment: Both to avoid problems with possible `NA` in the data, and to simplify, how about replacing  `res <- x*0 ;res[length(res)] <- 1`  with `res<-c(rep(0,length(x)-1),1)` ?

Comment: Sure, could be done. However, the former is more efficient for big vectors, which is most likely not a problem for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is convert a string of `111`'s' into a single `1`. If that's the case, the following should do it.

Broken down step by step:

```
# Likely they're factors.  Convert to strings.  # Dont convert to numeric if your data may have a series of approx 20+ 1's 
dataFrame$def <- as.character(dataFrame$def)

# Find which ones have any 1's at all
indxOf1s <- grep("1", dataFrame$def)

# Convert those to a single 1
  x <- gsub("1", "0", dataFrame$def[indxOf1s])    
  dataFrame$def[indxOf1s] <-  paste0(substr(x, 1, nchar(x)-1), rep(1, length(x)) )

dataFrame

        BEFORE      &          AFTER

    Comp    def             Comp    def
  1    A   1111           1    A   0001
  2    B   1111           2    B   0001
  3    C      0           3    C      0
  4    D 111111           4    D 000001
  5    E      1           5    E      1
  6    F 111111           6    F 000001
  7    G 111111           7    G 000001
  8    H  11111           8    H  00001
```

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. Sorry for my imperfect explanation. Basically my dataframe contains 3 columns. 1st column year, 2nd column company code and 3rd column default (0 for no default and 1 for default). But if company defaulted in 2000 and my dataframe contains the company financials from 1990, the column for that particular company (company code i.e. 1004) has 10 times 1 in the column of "def". Rather it should be 1990 = 0, 1991 = 0, 1992 = 0 .... 1999 = 0, 2000 = 1.

Comment: so you want to have all those 0's in one column?  how should they be represented? `000001`,   `c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)`?

Comment: yes as c(0,0,0...1), but it has been done now, thank you very much for your affords and help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you really need to split the data first, change everything that's not the max year to 0 if there's a 1 in the def column, and then combine it back together.

```
l <- split(dataFrame, data.Frame$coKey)
l <- lapply(l, function(x){ 
               if (1 %in% x$def) x$def[x$fyear != max(x$fyear)] <- 0
               x})
data.Frame <- do.call(rbind, l)
```